# HTTP request pending too slow

Tags: google-chrome, http, networking

here is some log from `chrome://net-internals/#events`

```
HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=18581 [st=   2]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=2744]
t=18581 [st=   2]        HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS  [dt=2744]
t=21325 [st=2746]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS
```

and the request pending almost 2700 ms. How can I solve this problem?

I have test that client,internet speed is fast,and ping my domain, also normal;
server(other user response quickly) and api(this api just print current time) also ok,

Answer (score 0):

There may be several reasons of it

1. internet speed may be slow.
2. server configuration may be lower then required (RAM and processor).
3. too much conditions in api that you calling or there may complicated query in api(with joins and sub query).

check above possibilities in your code.

Comment: all above I have checked, and haven`t found any problem

Comment: are you using apache http request ??